# Firefox Dev Tools: Is it possible to see event listeners on document?

Tags: javascript, firefox, event-handling, dom-events, firefox-developer-tools

Besides being able to see event handlers on DOM elements, is there a way to see event handlers on the document as well?

[image: I]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The firefox inspector shows them as attached to the `<html>` tag at the top of the page being inspected. Proof by inspection :-)